# is it right way to load library in static block?

Tags: java, opencv, spring-boot

I am using opencv library in my application through maven dependency. I am loading opencv in static block when application starts. Still,I am working in development environment and it is working fine.But i want to ask,is it a right way to load opencv in static block ?

**Loading opencv**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SamepinchApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

static {
        try{
            nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
            System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        }catch(Exception exception){
            System.out.println("Open CV Library could not load due to " + exception.getCause());
        }
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SamepinchApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>nu.pattern</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9-7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please help me,what is a good practice to load opencv or other native library ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loading a native library in static block is good practice. However there are a few  things to keep in mind.

A class could be loaded once only (leaving the occasional respective Classloader garbage collection, which may unload it providing the opportunity for reload) , so if something goes wrong with the library loading, you'll probably have to restart your JVM or reload this class somehow manually.

For example if you're loading library in static block of a REST service or Servlet, and library was not loaded for some reason, you have to redeploy the application or restart the Application server to reload the class to run the static block again for the next try.

However if the library was loaded somewhere other than static block, it can be loaded in the next call of the service or servlet HTTP method.
Multiple calls to System.loadLibrary() don't do anything, if the library is loaded already, so there's no side effect.

All that said, in my opinion loading a native library in a static block is the way to go.